# "Inheriting" instance of wrapped type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a type that basically acts as a tag on another data type:

```
import Data.Word
data RijndaelField = RF Word8
```

I want `RijndaelField` to "inherit" the `Word8` instance of `Bits` in the simplest way possible:

```
import Data.Bits
instance Bits RijndaelField where
    RF a .&. RF b     = RF $ a .&. b
    RF a .|. RF b     = RF $ a .|. b
    RF a `xor` RF b   = RF $ a `xor` b
    complement (RF a) = RF $ complement a
    shift (RF a) n    = RF $ shift a n
    rotate (RF a) n   = RF $ rotate a n
    bitSize (RF a)    = bitSize a
    isSigned (RF a)   = isSigned a
    testBit (RF a) n  = testBit a n
    bit n             = RF $ bit n
    popCount (RF a)   = popCount a
```

Is there a shorter way to express that relation between `RijndaelField` and `Word8`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't need ADTs or record types, you could use a `newtype` instead with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

newtype RF = RF { unRF :: Word8 } deriving (Eq, Bits)
```

---

If you really wanted to, you can include a lot of other classes

```
newtype RF = RF { unRF :: Word8 }
    deriving (Eq, Bits, Num, Integral, Real, Enum, Ord, Show)
```

Which would let you use it as

```
> 1 :: RF
RF {unRF = 1}
> [1..5] :: [RF]
[RF {unRF = 1},RF {unRF = 2},RF {unRF = 3},RF {unRF = 4},RF {unRF = 5}]
> let x = RF 1
> x + 2
RF {unRF = 3}
```

Which I think it quite handy

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. (There's an extension for everything!)

Comment: @Snowball Just about =)  This one is particularly useful when wrapping up a stack of monad transformers, you can have the compiler derive things like `Monad`, `Functor`, `MonadTrans`, `MonadState MyState`, `Applicative`, and more.  It's very handy for generating a lot of boilerplate code.